Downloading bulk nucleotide and protein data from GISAID EpiFlu
I am trying to download all influenza protein and nucleotide data from GISAID to process it further in a more friendly environment.
How can I do this programmatically? (or with any method, I am open to any suggestions)

Check whether it has an API

I suspect that doing something like this would go against the GISAID Terms of Use:

b. Use of the GISAID EpiFlu™ Database and Data. You acknowledge and agree that you may not access and use the GISAID EpiFlu™ Database or collect, store, reproduce, access, modify, display, distribute, coordinate, arrange, and otherwise use the Data in connection with any other database related to influenza gene sequences, including, without limitation, by enabling others to access or use the Data through a separate portal or across a network of institutions, except for operators duly authorized by GISAID.
...
d. Distribution of Data. Subject to applicable law, You agree not to distribute Data to any third party other than Authorized Users as contemplated by this Agreement.
...

Use of the Database Platform. You acknowledge and agree that:

The GISAID EpiFlu™ Database utilizes a proprietary platform and software technology (collectively, the "Database Platform") owned by GISAID and/or third party contractors.
You will not copy, reverse engineer, disseminate or disclose any part of the Database Platform.




